# Link HTML form to Django field

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I am new to HTML, my problem is I can't make a form field to be linked to the form.field I try to link with. I had to write an HTML form manually and not simply use the {{form.field}} because I am using a datepicker with JQuery.

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
  {{ form.valida_desde.errors }}
    <label for="id_valida_desde">Válida desde:</label>
    <input  type="text" data-date-format="mm/dd/yy" id="valida_desde"> 
</div>
```

I could easily render this required field by doing:

```
{{ form.valida_desde.errors }}
{{ form.valida_desde }}
```

But that would not work with datepicker. So, what do I do so that the first form saves the data to form.valida_desde field, which is a DateField BTW.

The Jquery needed at the bottom, it works OK

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#valida_desde" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

EDIT:

Actually is pretty funny for the fact that I just found the answer after looking for more than 3 hours.

```
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
      {{ form.valida_desde.errors }}
        <label for="id_valida_desde">Válida desde:</label>
        <input  type="text" name="valida_desde" data-date-format="mm/dd/yy" id="valida_desde"> 
    </div>
```

Adding the name attribute made it, I did that but tried something like form.valida_desde and even {{ form.valiad_desde }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually is pretty funny for the fact that I just found the answer after looking for more than 3 hours.

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
  {{ form.valida_desde.errors }}
    <label for="id_valida_desde">Válida desde:</label>
    <input  type="text" name="valida_desde" data-date-format="mm/dd/yy" id="valida_desde"> 
</div>
```

Adding the name attribute made it, I did that but tried something like form.valida_desde and even {{ form.valiad_desde }}